# SQL Server Linked Server Error

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to send some tables from sql server 2008(Head Office) to sql server 2008 express(Client Side).Both servers are in different locations.My Client Side server name is dynamic.
I am executing the stored procedure which is below:

```
@BranchServerName= 'ClientServerName\Sqlexpress'

if  exists(select * from sys.servers where name = @BranchServerName)
begin
    EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin @BranchServerName, NULL
             EXEC sp_dropserver @BranchServerName, NULL;
     end
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.servers where name = @BranchServerName)
begin
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @BranchServerName,N'SQL Server';
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@BranchServerName, 
@useself='false',
    @rmtuser='sa',
    @rmtpassword='*******'
end

set  @sqlCmd = 'A big Sql Query'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd

if  exists(select * from sys.servers where name = @BranchServerName)
begin
    EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin @BranchServerName, NULL
    EXEC sp_dropserver @BranchServerName, NULL;
end
```

Sometimes I am getting the following errors not all times:

1. Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists
2. Could not find server 'ClientSide\SQLEXPRESS' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Please help me to solve this problem. It's really making me crazy. I have checked lots of articles but I could not make out where am I wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Second Editing :

Second Trial Using OpenRowSet:
I have used the below coding

Second Trial Using OpenRowSet:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=ClientServer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ClientDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=*****',
'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;  
INSERT INTO [ClientServer\SQLEXPRESS].ClientDB.dbo.TB_ClientTable
        SELECT  * FROM  TB_ServerTable
          WHERE TransHdrID= 45 and SourceID=3453
       ')
```

Note : TB_ClientTable name and TB_ServerTable name are similar. In above I am inserting into only one table but I have to insert into 6 tables. My ClientServerName are dynamic. I am using very long Dynamic query.The above one is the small sample which should work. But I am getting the following error:

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 2
Could not find server '192.168.14.42\SQLEXPRESS' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Please guide me or Please correct me.

Third Editing:

Third Editing

Any ideas how to proceed the below using Openrowset:

```
Declare @ID nvarchar(10)
set @ID='1234' 
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=ClientServer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ClientDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=*****',
'IF (EXISTS(SELECT * 
    FROM ClientDB.dbo.ClientTableName TransHdrID
    where ID='+@ID+')) 
 begin
    delete from ClientDB.dbo.ClientTableName where ID='+@ID+'
     (Want to get value from ClientServer)           
     SELECT Field1,Field2
     FROM ClientDB.dbo.ClientTableName
 end 
else
 begin
           (Want to get value from ClientServer) 
    SELECT Field1,Field2
    FROM ClientDB.dbo.ClientTableName
 end')
    SELECT Field1,Field2
    FROM LocalDB.dbo.LocalTableName
    WHERE ID=@ID
```

Please help me how to so achieve above one. I am sure there is a syntax error. I am not getting proper solution from google surfing. Also tell me can I do the above one using SSIS.Please guide me

Comment: Have you considered using `OPENROWSET`? Have you considered using SSIS? SSIS is far more reliable than using linked servers on the fly. How many tables do you have to copy? There are far more sophisticated methods than this, i.e. replication and message queues

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked SSIS. It needs same version or higher version of sql server in the client side.But we can have only sql express in our client side. I have to send data from 6 tables.Moreover, Tables schema will not be same both side. I have no idea about openrow set.

Comment: Let me explain what I need.We are developing Point Of Sale System.We have call center from our Head office. when call center punches the orders we have to send the orders to our restaurant. I have checked MicroSoft DataSync and Replication. No use of it.

Comment: If you are pushing data from head office to a client you only need SSIS installed on head office side. You do not need it installed on the client side. Why don't you do some investigation on Openrowset. The 'Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists' error occur simply because the login you are using to connect has not been given access to the database, which is unexepcted since you are using sa (always a bad idea)

Comment: Please check my orignal post above. I have tried Openrowset.

Comment: Use OPENROWSET in this format: `INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('connection string','SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM ClientDB.dbo.TB_ClientTable') SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM LocalDB.dbo.YourLocalTable`. Here is an example inserting into a text file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269034/insert-into-openrowset-using-sqlserver-2000. You can try OPENROWSET but you will probably have the same problems as linked servers. You should really consider other methods like SSIS.

Comment: Thanks, I will try SSIS and get back to you

Comment: No. I am thinking to try with Openrowset, if it fails then go on with SSIS. I will get back to you after my trails. Please guide me with some article links regarding SSIS. Thanks LAMA

Comment: Please check my third Editing in original post above.

Comment: At least post the error. Anyway you can't INSERT into the query you are using. The query insisde OPENROWSET is a local query run on the remote server, so..   1. Do not use the remote server name anywhere in the query. 2. The pass through query has to be a simple select from a table. YOU have something far more complex there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET
('SQLNCLI',
'Server=ClientServer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ClientDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=*****',
'SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM ClientDB.dbo.TB_ClientTable')

SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM LocalDB.dbo.TB_ClientTable
```

The OPENROWSET part returns a rowset that you insert into. You can't put anything complex in there or it doesn't know how to insert it.

But you should look at SSIS - it looks like you are trying to do some kind of differential data logic (which was not mentioned in your question)

Comment: Thanks Lama. I am using linked Server. It is working like a charm. The mistake is, I was creating linked server connection in my stored procedures.So, In every procedure I was creating and dropping the linked server connectivity. Now only once that is I have manually created linked server. Now no issues.